# Using std::find to start from a certain value

Tags: c++11

What I would like to do is to start an std::find through a vector from a certain place inside the vector

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
for (int a = 0; a < myvector.size(); a++){
    it = find(myvector.begin() + a, myvector.end(), myvector.at(a));
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

I can't simply add 'a' in the find command. How would I achieve the same effect?

Comment: How do you decide the *certain place*?

Comment: In this code it is trying to be determined by the int 'a', but that does not work.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You are looking for the `a`-th item starting from the `a`-th item. You will always find it.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking, but I *think* you're looking for std::advance

Comment: `myvector.begin() + 3` does work AFAIK

Comment: This is an XY problem.  As written, `find()` will always immediately "find" what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for a value after it first occurred you could try this:

```
auto it2 = std::find(
    std::next(std::find(std::begin(myvector), std::end(myvector), val)),
    std::end(myvector), val);
}
```

it first finds the first occurrence of the value, and starts searching again from the next position.

You could use [`std::next()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)
to increment an iterator like:

```
it = find(std::next(myvector.begin(), a), myvector.end(), myvector.at(a));
```